# Query to find all documents with non-zero milliseconds

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There is a large collection of `transaction` documents (~2M)

Each `transaction` document has a `source.billDate` field:

```
"source.billDate" : ISODate("2018-07-23T16:02:06.797Z")
// or //
"source.billDate" : ISODate("2018-07-22T14:21:56.000Z")
```

**As you can see some dates have milliseconds and some don't.**

I'm wondering if there is a way to use MongoDB query to find `transaction` documents that have milliseconds in their `billDate` date.

Is it possible, if so, how?

Comment: They both have milliseconds but one if them milliseconds of zero

Comment: @BasilBattikhi well yes, you can't really have an ISODate without milliseconds.

Comment: @BasilBattikhi The problem is that correct format for us is WITHOUT milliseconds, but there was a bug that added milliseconds, which in turn cause a lot of problems. So I'm trying to find an efficient way to set milliseconds to 0

Comment: so do you want only first document with millisecond `"797"`?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet no, **all** documents whose millisecond value is not 0.

Comment: yes but from above you have to find first one? because it has "797"

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below queries in mongodb **3.6** version

You have to first extract millisecond from your `date` using [**`$dateToParts`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/) and then you can easily match with the documents having millisecond [**`$ne`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/) 0

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$ne": [
        { "$millisecond": {
          "date": "$source.billDate",
          "timezone": "America/New_York"
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Or with find query as well

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$ne": [
      { "$millisecond": {
        "date": "$source.billDate",
        "timezone": "America/New_York"
      }},
      0
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: This is a **perfect** solution. Thanks a lot!